# Don't change URL on Place change in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

i have a question about GWT. In GWT when i navigate to a new Place it changes URL address in browser bar. So is  there any solution to not change the URL when going to new Place. Code example with goTo method is below.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      super.onFailure(caught);
      ForbiddenPlace forbiddenPlace = new ForbiddenPlace();
      goTo(forbiddenPlace);
}
```

Comment: Could you not load the url into an iframe? So long as it is within the same domain, you can get the document content and work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `PlaceController.goTo` method, it will fire a `PlaceChangeEvent` in the eventBus, this will be used by both `PlaceHistoryHandler` and `ActivityManager`. It is the `PlaceHistoryHandler` the one that is updating the URL (`Historian`), so... if you just want to show the place without updating the URL (`Historian`) you can manually supply the place to your `ActivityManager` using `ActivityManager.onPlaceChange(new PlaceChangeEvent(new ForbiddenPlace()))`.